# how to assign an incremental value to evey line in a file in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to read a file, and for each row I'd like to attach a row number in the file to it. So the result should be like

```
[1 "line1"]
[2 "line2"]
[3 "line3"]
```

How to do that effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for `line-seq`.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(with-open [f (io/reader (io/file "test-file"))]
  (mapv vector (next (range)) (line-seq f)))

[[1 "line1"] [2 "line2"] [3 "line3"]]
```

I use `mapv` here, because laziness and finite resources like file handles don't mix.

Comment: `(next range)` instead of `(map inc (range))`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it does not fit your need but the generic function `map-indexed` is worth to know:

```
(map-indexed 
   (fn [index line] [(inc index) line]) 
   (line-seq f))
```